# Array Vlookup Importrange to get the Data from different Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using below formula which is working very fine. But it is just loading the single column Data which is Column W3:W500 I want to get the other columns Data as well that are X, Y, Z and AA, AB.

I tried by expanding this range `W3:W500` to `W3:AA500` but nothing worked. Your help will be appreciated.

[Formula Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12fQheyS6nVE9sP4BimL6WfQWLIuJ3CUMeZHWIwSqZtg/edit#gid=0)

[Data Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VD0JgUXvV9SKBF7KBGnv0nayQd_R5TE-TzvKDv6sveM/edit#gid=0)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B3:B501="",,vlookup(trim(B3:B501&" "&C3:C501&" "&text(F3:F501, "mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&G3:G501), {transpose(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(query(IMPORTRANGE("Sheetname","Sheet1!A3:W500"), "Select Col2, Col3, Col6, Col7")),,9^9)), IMPORTRANGE("Sheetname","Sheet1!W3:AA500")} ,2,0)))
```

Comment: All of your sheets are locked. Please change the permissions to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only requested column 2 to be returned at the end of your `VLOOKUP`, i.e., `,2,0)`.

See the newly added "Erik Help" sheet, where I replaced your `2` (ie., your request for only the second column of data) with `{2,3,4,5}` (i.e., a request for columns 2, 3, 4 and 5 of data).

I'm confused, however, as to why you are requesting `A3:W500` in your first `IMPORTRANGE` call, if you only need the data from `A3:G500`; and likewise, why you are calling for `W3:AA500` in the second `IMPORTRANGE`, if you only need `W3:Z500`.

Comment: Thank you very much i was not aware that i should change vlookup criteria as well. Thank you once again.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was an easy spot and fix to get you moving forward again.

Comment: Thank you for the help Sir.